# aggregate has incomplete type and cannot be defined when dealing with default template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming

I want to try to forward declare a templated class with a default template parameter.

My code looks like this:

```
 template <typename T = int> class temp;

 int main()
 {
      temp<> def; // error here
 }

 template <typename T>
 class temp
 {
     T val;
 public:
     temp() = default;
     // other stuff can go here, not relevant though
 }
```

I am working in c++11. Is there any way around this error or am I just stuck?

Comment: You can't use a concrete type before it is defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration/33448221#33448221

Comment: Not directly realted, but it is going to bite you one day: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I see this comment often. But I think it is okay for examples and illustrative purposes.

Comment: @TrickorTreat I don't.

Comment: @TrickorTreat Given that there's no single thing that would need these two lines, I assumed that it's just "file default" for OP. And even for minimal reproducible example on SO I'd be afraid to use that, given the vast amount of names residing in namespace std - it's a russian roulette with the compiler.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'm well aware, this is not my actual code, just something short to illustrate the point

Comment: Which part of it is required to illustrate the point?